# couldn't add string to listview after using volley

Tags: android

used volley to get data from api but it couldn't be save to listView.
It can be shown is Toast But it doestn't save in arraylist.

Json :

```
[{"name":"Sohail Bashir Chughtai","age":"29","success":true},
 {"name":"Umair Aslam","age":"27","success":true},
 {"name":"Taha Tahir","age":"0","success":true}
]{"status":200,"status_message":"Patient Found","data":null}
```

MainActivity.java

```
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.android.volley.Request;
import com.android.volley.Response;
import com.android.volley.VolleyError;
import com.android.volley.toolbox.JsonArrayRequest;
import com.android.volley.toolbox.JsonObjectRequest;

import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    String jsonUrl = "http://shifa.com.pk/rest_api/api.php?mr_no=all";
     Button button;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        final ArrayList<String> arrayList = new ArrayList<String>();

        ListView listView = findViewById(R.id.listView);
        ArrayAdapter<String> arrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(getApplicationContext(),android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,arrayList );

         button = findViewById(R.id.button);   

        button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                final JsonArrayRequest jsonArrayRequest = new JsonArrayRequest(Request.Method.POST, jsonUrl, null, new Response.Listener<JSONArray>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onResponse(JSONArray response) {


                        for(int i = 0; i < response.length(); i++){
                            JSONObject jresponse = null;
                            try {
                                jresponse = response.getJSONObject(i);
                            } catch (JSONException e) {
                                e.printStackTrace();
                            }
                            String nickname ="";
                            try {

                                nickname = jresponse.getString("name");

                            } catch (JSONException e) {
                                e.printStackTrace();

                            }


                            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, nickname, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                            arrayList.add(nickname.toString());



                        }


                    }
                }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {

                        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Error", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }
                });

                MySingelton.getInstance(MainActivity.this).addToRequestQueu(jsonArrayRequest);
            }
        });


        listView.setAdapter(arrayAdapter);

    }

}
```

Layout

```
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginEnd="103dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="111dp"
        android:text="Click mE"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/listView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"


        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"></ListView>
```

Comment: Your API returns invalid json

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your `onCreate()` method you need to set the adapter of your `ListView` like this:

```
ListView listView = findViewById(R.id.listView);
ArrayAdapter<String> arrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(getApplicationContext(),android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,arrayList );
listView.setAdapter(arrayAdapter);
```

Then after you have looped through the `JSONArray` you need to let the `ListView` know that the data set has been updated. It might seem odd that you notify the `ArrayAdapter` instead of the `ListView`. So do this:

```
arrayAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
```

---

Edit: 
After looking closer to the code I see that you have `listView.setAdapter(arrayAdapter);` down at the bottom of the `onCreate()` method. There is no need to separate your code like this--this makes it harder to read and analyze.

Comment: I have tried the method you described but it still doesn't work 
and show nothing in listview

Comment: Thanks man  I was Really missing arrayAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged()